# UITableView rearrange sections with 1 row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView with 3 sections, each containing 1 row. When edit mode is enabled, I want the user to be able to rearrange the sections without change the amount of rows (always 1) in each section.

**Start**

[image: UITableView with 3 sections each containing 1 row]

**Dragging**

[image: UITableview dragging row 1]

**End - What I want to avoid**

[image: UITableView with 3 sections each containing 1 row]

**I found a solution** that is working, but without animations. If I update the datamodel and reload the tableView in `moveRowAtIndexPath` the tableView looks as it should.. It would be nice to replace the `reloadData()` with an actual `tableView begin` and `endUpdates`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let movedProperty = list[sourceIndexPath.section]
    list.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.section)
    list.insert(movedProperty, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.section)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath
}
```

Comment: can you post your code for number or row in section and how you manage list array

Comment: It's a bit complicated, because the reason for this approach is that each sections is collapsable (= more rows in 1 section) Drag&Drop is not possible when a section is opened so for the sake of this example numberOfRowsInSection always returns 1 and list is an array of Strings: ["1", "2", "3"] which you can re-order. Hope this helps.